# Azure deployment of MVC .net project from git repository failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-deployment

After MUCH tribulation messing around with what to include I got my site deployed in azure from my repository in git.

However I am now having more problems with libraries, specifically: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, ..."

I thought that azure was supposed to handle the package/library dependencies, why is it falling over on this one? Any insight into what I'm missing would be much appreciated - thanks!

My project is using MVC 4

Comment: Did you check the GAC?

Comment: @StevenPenny erm how?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Needed to install the ASP.NET Web API Web Host package: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/data-access/details/manually-installing-references-required-by-the-web-api-service
Although now I'm having database connection problems (I used code-first...)

Comment: Follow up - finally got my site working: I updated my project to the newest version of MVC and that solved assembly errors, then decided to change my project to database-first and then hosted the database separately on azure and modified the connection strings accordingly. Huzzah!